# multiple count in a single query in oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to get output from :

```
select count(r.id) and count(r.key) from rules r where lower(r.name) in ('xss attack','dos attack') ;
```

but getting error like

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: What happens if you try select count(r.id), count(r.key) from rules r where lower(r.name) in ('xss attack','dos attack') ;

Comment: please check my answer which i replied for above question and what I'm expecting @ProgrammersBlock

Comment: the `and` in your select list is causing your original problem.  Look at Renato's answer below for correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? :

```
select count(r.id),count(r.key) from rules
where lower(r.name) in ('xss attack','dos attack')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below solution :

```
select (select count(r.id) from rules r where lower(r.name) in ('xss attack','dos attack')) AS name,(select count(r.key) from rules r where lower(r.name) in ('xss attack','dos attack')) AS name from rules;
```

Please correct me if any improvement is required for above query.

Output I'm getting is like

```
NAME   NAME

 2      2
 2      2
```

while i expect my output should like as

```
NAME        NAME
 2            2
```